# Invalid Cast Exception occurring

Tags: wpf

```
int[] checkeditemslist = new int[ChkList.Items.Count];//ChkList is Listbox name in xaml

ListBoxItem lt =((ListBoxItem)ChkList.Items[i]);
```

Now I'm getting error 
An exception of type `System.InvalidCastException` occurred  but was not handled in user code
Unable to cast object of type `CheckListItem` to type `System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem`.

Comment: well the exceptions tells you already whats wrong. you're checklist contains "CheckListItems"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListItem liCheckedItems in ChkList.Items)
            {
    checkedItems.add(liCheckedItems.Value)
    }
```

Comment: I'm having 4 items in my checked listbox and need to loop though items and if checked values should be concatenated.By using foreach this is not done i supposwe

Comment: List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListItem liCheckedItems in ChkList.Items)
            {
    checkedItems.add(liCheckedItems.Value)
    }
 
 string result;
 
 result = string.Join("~", checkedItems.ToArray());
 
---------------------- 

if checked items val is dog,cat,mouse

output would look like "dog~cat~mouse"

Comment: thats why we need here to utilize string.join and ToArray function to convert the list to array then join them together to create the concatinated string

Comment: Oh,Thanks a lot.Going to try this one

Comment: Sry,i tried using code as said above,but showing two errors.  1. Showing error at ListItem in foreach loop as type or namespace could not be found and 2. 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add this on the top "using System.Collections.Generic;" since list is part of the this library

Answer (score 0):

As the error says it's a type cast error, your `ChkList` contains items of class `CheckListItem` and you are trying to cast them to `ListBoxItem` and thus the system is generating `System.InvalidCastException` (Invalid Cast Exception)

Please ensure that you are filling the list with objects of the correct class and while retrieving the objects from the same list type cast the objects from the list to it's correct class.